# enable SMART for HP hard disk

Tags: centos, hard-disk, smartctl, dmidecode

I would like to use SMART to perform a health check of my hard disk. I have an HP server of 4 years ago I believe. Every time I try to use the following command

```
 smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

I got an error message saying the following

```
 Device does not support SMART

 Error Counter logging not supported
 Device does not support Self Test logging
```

Does it really mean that there is no way I can use SMART on these disk, or is it just because I am missing some driver or my BIOS is too old?

According to `dmidecode` I have bios 2.7 so it should be not too old.

I am using CentOS 6.4.

Comment: What type of disk is this? (SATA, IDE, SCSI, SAS, FibreChannel, etc.)

Comment: Do you connect your hard-drive via USB? If so, maybe this would help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109691/which-smartctl-d-option-should-i-use-on-this-hard-disk-scsi-or-ata .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely reason is that your server came with a hardware raid controller and sda is not an individual disk, but a logical drive.

HP provides tools to monitor your hardware, the typical Linux utility to monitor HP raid controller status and the drives contained would be `hpacucli` found [here](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/ProLiantSupportPack/RedHat/6Server/packages/x86_64/).

Some useful commands would be:

```
hpacucli> ctrl all show config 
hpacucli> ctrl all show config detail
hpacucli> ctrl all show status

hpacucli> ctrl slot=0 pd all show 
hpacucli> ctrl slot=0 pd 1 show
hpacucli> ctrl slot=0 pd all show status
```

Comment: Yes. There is RAID. Why this RAID makes sMART complicated to use? I read about this difficulty elsewhere. Is this going to complicate and make impossible to use SMART or it is really just a matter of using the right tool?

Comment: SMART is a set of disk properties, a logical drive consists of multiple disks, so that doesn't align. The RAID controller could interpret the status of the underlying disks and present a SMART like interface, but typically the RAID driver and/or manufacterer tooling provides better or more relevant status information.

Comment: @HBruijn This is correct. I often say that S.M.A.R.T. is *not* the final word in storage monitoring. In the HP Smart Array case, the controllers use SMART amongst a number of other methods to determine drive and array health.

Answer (score 5):

To add to what Aleksandr said (I can't comment yet, unfortunately):

> smartctl -x -A -d sat+cciss,0 /dev/sda

The sat+ bit gets you more than just cciss on its own - in particular, you should be able to access the individual attributes, not just the overall SMART status and computed values.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use repos as write here - http://sysadmin.te.ua/linux/hpraid-monitoring.html

```
echo 'deb http://hwraid.le-vert.net/ubuntu precise main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raid.list
```

This repo has almost all raid monitoring utils for all type of raids!
Also article shows how to monitor HP raid using 'smartctl' as well.

```
smartctl -a -d cciss,0 /dev/sda
```

Regards.

Comment: actually this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @kiltek I agree with you. This solution works best even on CentOS

Answer (score 2):

> `Device does not support SMART`

This can mean one of two things:

1. The named hard disk indeed does not support SMART. In that case, you are out of luck with that particular drive.
2. `smartctl` has no clue how to talk to the disk. If that is the case, you *may* have a little bit of luck with carefully trying various parameter values for `--device`; see the smartctl man page for details.

BIOS version is completely unrelated to whether the disk drive supports SMART or not. Whether a drive supports SMART is a property of the drive, or more accurately the drive firmware.